# Use R to do monte carlo simulation and solve following questions

Tags: r

My question is:  how to generate two time-series of the length of 100 generated from the following data generating process:

```
xt = xt−1 + et, 
yt = yt−1 + ut,
```

where `et` and `ut` are mutually independent standard normal i.i.d. series. In a regression of `yt` on `xt` including intercept, simulate the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis that the slope coefficient alpha  is zero, with the 5 percent nominal size.

1. Do the simulation for different values of alpha = 0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99.
2. Discuss your results. How does the rejections probability change as the value of alpha changes?

My thought is that I generate two arima series by coding

```
y <- arima.sim(100,model=list(ar=0))
x <- arima.sim(100,model=list(ar=0))
```

then do the regression y on x and store the value of alpha, and repeat the above steps for 1000 times, and find the distribution of alpha.
But my problem is:

1. I don't know how to store the value of alpha
2. how to repeat regression for 1000 times

I'm a new learner of R, hope someone can tell me how to solve this problem by writing R codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

# define a function the returns the alpha -- its point estimate, standard error, etc. -- from the OLS
iteration <- function() {
  y <- arima.sim(100,model=list(ar=0))
  x <- arima.sim(100,model=list(ar=0))
  lm(y~x) %>% 
    broom::tidy() %>% 
    filter(term == 'x')
}

# 1000 iterations of the above simulation
alphas <- map_df(1:1000, ~iteration())

# plot the results
alphas %>% 
  ggplot(aes(estimate)) + geom_density()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want! I successfully draw the density plot of the estimated alphas. But I found that I don't know how to calculate the rejection possibility of each alpha value. Do you know how to count rejection possibility using R? Or how can I list some detailed information of this density function?